# Hubspot automatic payments reommendation

Tags: online-payment

I hope I'm asking the correct community. I'm an intern at a company that sells a software. All this time, the company sales department would ask the customers, one by one, for the payment of the software. The manager wants to add automatic payments for the customers, like subscriptions. We recently started using HubSpot and that's where we have our customers. I was asked to research and help with this project. I saw that the integration of HubSpot and Stripe doesn't go smoothly for a lot of people. I thought about integrating the HubSpot API and Stripe API in Postman but I also saw that HubSpot already has a Payments and Invoicing system. I'm not entirely sure how to move towards this.
Any idea is welcomed.